# How can I use a regular expression to find content in a page with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, match, template-engine

So I've been trying to do $(document).match(/regexp/); and I keep getting "undefined is not a function"

When I do $(document)html().match(/regexp/); TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

The regexp I'm using is /^[~{.*?}~]$/
All I want to do is search the html document for [~{ any kind of input }~] so that I can then replace it with the right code using jQuery. Essentially, I'll be creating my own templating engine. The current ones, either don't do what I need, or are over bloated.

```
<body>

    [~{ header }~]


    <p>This is the home page</p>


    [~{ footer }~]

</body>
```

So I guess I wasn't clear, what I need to do is find text within "[~{" and "}~]". Then after placing it within a variable and determining what to do with it, I'll then find the entire expression again, but this time I'll replace it with other content.

So

```
[~{ header }~]
```

I would find this with match or something, extract the "header" text into a variable. From there I'll have it go through a function. The function will return something to do like retrieve getting an html page and load it. But it'll then have to find the expression again to replace it.

Comment: So basically you want to use regex to create a templating engine? Sounds splendid.

Comment: yeah, I figured that I could just find an text node and then replace it with content or load a page.

Comment: Yeah, regex is great for parsing HTML, but right now you're using the "string starts with" and "string ends with" so it's not matching.

Comment: So would I have to just search for the string starts with expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document)` returns a jQuery object, not a string. You need to call `html()` to get the HTML contents of the document. You can do:

```
$('body').html(function(contents) {
    return contents.replace(/regexp/, 'replacement');
});
```

If you just want to see the match:

```
var match = $('body').html().match(/regexp/);
console.log(match);
```

Comment: How would I been able to see what it returned? I need to be able to see the contents of the regexp found. Thanks!

Comment: That was the second thing I tried, which gave a TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Comment: Hmm, `$(document).html()` returns `null`. I changed to `$('body')`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. The only thing left that is needed is retrieving /^[~{.*?}~]$/, if I place the text node "regexp" and do a .match(/regexp/) it returns the text node "regexp". However, when I put in a more complex regexp, it simply returns null.

Comment: If it's returning null, there's nothing that matches the regexp you gave. Don't forget that `[` has special meaning in a regular expression, you have to escape it if you want it to be matched literally.

Comment: Also, the `^` and `$` anchors match the beginning and end of the document. You don't want those in your regexp, since you want to match the templates anywhere in the document.

Comment: So I'm trying this now:

match = $('body').html().match(/\[~\{ .*? \}~\]/);
console.log(match);

i guess it doesn't like my expression, however when I go to http://regexpal.com/ it'll show the what I want to be found. I did take your advice and remove the ^$

Comment: You still arent escaping the square brackets. Try: `/\[~\{.*?\}~\]/`.

Comment: Maybe you did escape them, but I couldn't see it. Put code inside backticks to make it show up literally in the comment.

Comment: Also, if the text inside the brackets can span multiple lines, you need the `s` modifier to allow `.` to match newlines.

Comment: Oh wow, I totally had a fail, I didn't wait for the DOM to load.
Once I placed the code within $(function(){ }) it worked, ish so far it only loaded the first expression

Comment: If you want it to match multiple times, you have to use the `g` modifier. Then it returns an array of all matches.

Comment: ahh yes the g, aha, your amazing! thank you very much!

Comment: I have another question if your interested. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163396/is-it-possible-to-chain-jquery-regexp-matches