# Is it possible to chain jQuery Regexp matches?

Tags: jquery, regex, optimization, match, template-engine

So I'm just curious if there was a way to chain regexp. Just looking to optimize my code a little. I want to find an expression, then find another one from the results.

The Working Code:

```
match = $('body').html().match(/(\[~\{ .*? \}~\])/g);
console.log(match[0]);

findText = match[0].match(/\w+/);
console.log(findText);
```

What I've tried:

```
match = $('body').html().match(/(\[~\{ .*? \}~\])(\w+)/g);
console.log(match[0]);
```

produced an error

```
match = $('body').html().match(/(\[~\{ .*? \}~\])|(\w+)/g);
console.log(match[0]);
```

Found Expression 1 and then Found Expression 2 outside of expression 1.

My HTML:

```
[~{ header }~]

<p>This is the home page</p>

[~{ footer }~]
```

Comment: You want to write one regexp which actually selects what you are looking for, not chain together two partials.  `.match()` is a javascript string function, not a jquery function so ti returns an array of results (or null if nothign matches) which makes chaining (with error control) difficult.  What are you actually trying to acheive here?

Comment: In the body find [~{ anything }~], then extract anything out of what it found.

Comment: The working code section does exactly what I want it to do, just seeing if i could optimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used a capturing group for the word inside the `[~{ ... }~]` structure.

```
\[~\{ (\w+) \}~\]
```

The only difference is I matched `(\w+)` instead of `.*?`.  I also removed the capture group (`(...)`) that was around the whole expression, since it wasn't necessary.

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jX6eO7)

---

Now it is a little difficult to access multiple capture groups in Javascript, but I used some example code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14210948/703229) (thanks Mathias Bynens):

```
function getMatches(string, regex) {
    var matches = [];
    var match;
    while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
        matches.push(match);
    }
    return matches;
}

var myString = $('body').html();
var myRegEx = /\[~\{ (\w+) \}~\]/g;

var matches = getMatches(myString, myRegEx);
console.log(matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array[2]
  0: "[~{ header }~]"    // The whole match
  1: "header"            // The captured group
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqTAv/)

---

So your final code could look something like this (this is pseudo-code):

```
matches; // this is set from previous code block

for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    var needsToBeReplaced = matches[i][0];
    var template = getTemplate(matches[i][1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this just returns [~{ header }~] vs just returing header

Comment: @JemiloII see my final update.  It will be an array of matches.  Each match will be an array containing the entire match (`[~{ header }~]`) at the 0-index and the captured group (`header`) at the 1-index.

Comment: wow, this works really nice this way! I like the multi-demensional array format. This format will make it easier for replacing the code later with updated content easier.

 For jsfiddle, if you add https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js as an external resource, you get a debugger. http://jsfiddle.net/cqTAv/1/

Comment: @JemiloII dang I wish I could hug you for that JSFiddle tip, super handy for personal and SO use!